# How does a screen blurring software work (such as Antisnooper) work?

Tags: windows, privacy

Antisnooper is a screen blurring software that could blur registered windows when mouse is not hovering on it.

https://www.techworld.com/download/security/antisnooper-21-3329883/

Does anyone know how this is implemented? Could this be implemented to various Linux GUI desktops manager too?

Answer (score -1):

Let me answer my own question after some research.

1. It is not possible for a Windows app to blur client area of another Windows app. If this is allowed, it wouls violate security constrains of an OS; Unless the first app is the OS window manager.
2. Windows 8 and 8.1 support Aero Glass Transparency with Blur feature. However this feature was removed in Windows 10. It was later partially re-enabled for Start Menu and Taskbar in a major Windows update in 2018.
3. [Aero Glass for Windows 8.x+][1], a donate-ware uses software hooks to re-implement such this features for Windows 10. However the solution is Windows binary dependent. A new Windows update may break the operation.

So, unless Windows 10 has re-introduced the aero glass completely, it shall not be possible.

If you have found a good solution, please post here. Thanks.